# preg_match zip code & state not working

Tags: php, preg-match

Not sure why the below is not finding zip and state?

```
$str = 'contact_widget_statezip">NM&nbsp; 87035 ';
$pattern = '[A-Z]{2}\W{1,10}[0-9]{5}';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $amatches);
```

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: Maybe you want to use delimiters for your pattern?!

Comment: You just want the state and the zip code, right? I'd decode the entities then just look for any amount of white space between them, `([A-Z]{2})\s*([0-9]{5})`, or if you require whitespace change the `*` to a `+`. As @Rizier123 said you need the delimiters when running the regex in PHP. So my regex would be `~([A-Z]{2})\s*([0-9]{5})~` in your `$pattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
<?php
$str = 'contact_widget_statezip">NM&nbsp; 87035 ';
$pattern = '~([A-Z]{2})\s*([0-9]){5}~';
preg_match_all($pattern, html_entity_decode($str), $amatches);
print_r($amatches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NM? 87035
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => NM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87035
        )

)
```

This takes your string `NM&nbsp; 87035` and converts it to `NM  87035` because `&nbsp;` = . It then searches for two capital letters, any amount of whitespace, and then 5 numbers. If you require the whitespace change the `*` to a `+`..

Update...

The `\W{1,10}` doesn't work in your example because `\W` is the inverse of `\w` which is any word character. The ampersand, semicolon, and white space fall into that group but the `nbsp` doesn't. If you don't want to decode the entity and just ignore the whitespace you could use `[A-Z]{2}[[a-zA-Z0-9; &]{1,10}[0-9]{5}` then for the PHP it'd be...

```
<?php
$str = 'contact_widget_statezip">NM&nbsp; 87035 ';
$pattern = '~([A-Z]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9; &]{1,10}([0-9]{5})~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $amatches);
print_r($amatches);
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes this works, however, why would it need to be done.  Why doesn't \W{1,10} take of the &nbsp;

Comment: Updated with explanation and an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris,
Your input helped with this solution.
The below finds a zip code and state and ignores the junk in between without `html_entity_decode`.

```
$str = 'contact_widget_statezip">NM&nbsp; 87035 ';
$pattern = "\b[A-Z]{2}\b.{1,10}\b[0-9]{5}\b/s";
```